# Построение графиков в MPAndroidChart

Tags: java, android

Использую библиотеку по построению графика [MPAndroidChart](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/741).
Хочу сделать круговую диаграмму, она называется `PieChart`, но разработчик не указал как ее использовать.

Может знает кто-нибудь?

Comment: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/PieChartActivity.java не?

Answer (score 3):

Ну как же не указал?

1. Имеется [полная документация](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v2.2.4/javadoc/)
2. [Описание использования](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Specific-chart-settings)
3. [Пример использования](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/PieChartActivity.java)

Добавляете его в `xml`, а дальше в коде по примеру из п.3:

```
mChart = (PieChart) findViewById(R.id.chart1);
...
```